# "Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'show'") "

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I trying to show my icon while on  'https://developer.chrome.com/' , by the below mentioned code , by sending the message through a file
content.js , but I get the error

> Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'show')

Background script (eventPage.js) :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if (request.todo == "showPageAction")
    {
        chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow: true},async function(tabs){
             chrome.pageAction.show(tabs[0].id);
        });
    }
});
```

content.js :

`chrome.runtime.sendMessage({todo:"showPageAction"}) ;`

manifest.json :

```
{
    "manifest_version" :3 ,
    "name" : "PageFontstyle Extension" ,
    "version" :"1.0" ,
    "description" : "changes font style on a specific page" ,
    "icons" :{
        "128" :"icon128.jpg" ,
        "48" :"icon48.jpg" ,
        "16" :"icon16.jpg" 

    } ,
    "action" :{
        "default_icon" :"icon16.jpg" ,
        "default_popup" :"popup.html" ,
        "default_title" :"PageFontStyle" 
    },
    "background" :{
        "service_worker" : "eventPage.js" 
     
    } ,

    "content_scripts" :[{
        "matches" : ["https://developer.chrome.com/*"],
        "js" : ["content.js","jquery-3.7.0.min.js"]
    }
],

    "permissions" :[
        "tabs"
    ]

    

}
```

find [here](https://github.com/Akash-k-p/PageFontSyle)

Thanks .

Comment: On an unrelated note: You've misspelled "persistent" in `manifest.json` - And you don't even need the line `"persistent": false`, because you're using Manifest V3, which uses a service worker instead of a background page, and this service worker is automatically non-persistent.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, migrating a Manifest V2 extension to Manifest V3? Because there's documentation for that: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/migrating/

Comment: Content scripts can't use most of `chrome` API. Do it in your action or background scripts.

Comment: @wOxxOm - I think he's only using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` in his content script.

Comment: @akashKP - Is this EXACTLY the same code you're running on your computer, or did you change something before pasting it into your question? I'm asking because many people make "minor" changes to their code before posting it on SO, and these changes introduce major bugs.

Comment: @ThomasMueller , yes this is the same code that i'm running on my computer .

Comment: 1) You probably look at an old error in chrome://extensions page when your content script was incorrect. Click the trashcan icon or the `clear all` button to remove it, then reload the extension. 2) The current code doesn't seem meaningful and it's unclear which icon you want to show because the extension's icon is always shown in modern Chrome if it's pinned and there's no way to pin it programmatically anyway. Please describe the functionality of your extension in more detail.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm trying to make the icon16 , icon visible in the extension , which is manually pinned . I'm trying to implement [this](https://youtu.be/OTHtx4Z13ok?list=PLC3y8-rFHvwg2-q6Kvw3Tl_4xhxtIaNlY) video , but still uses manifest v3 though .

Comment: @akashKP - "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'show')" means the property to the left of `.show` is undefined. That property is `chrome.pageAction`. And `chrome.pageAction` is undefined because your extension uses Manifest V3, which doesn't have `browser_action` or `page_action`, only `action`. Please read [Migrate from Manifest V2 to Manifest V3 > Update your code > Replace Browser Actions and Page Actions with Actions](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/migrating/api-calls/#replace-browser-page-actions)

Comment: That youtube tutorial isn't useful for ManifestV3 because the icon is always visible and there's no more page action. You can change the icon conditionally though by using chrome.declarativeContent API or explicitly via chrome.action API.